# jq with multiple select statements and an array

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I've got some JSON like the following (I've filtered the output here):

```
[
  {
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "example1"
      },
     {
        "Key": "Irrelevant",
        "Value": "irrelevant"
      }
    ],

    "c7n:MatchedFilters": [
      "tag: example_tag_rule"
    ],
    "another_key": "another_value_I_dont_want"
  },
  {
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "example2"
      }
    ],

    "c7n:MatchedFilters": [
      "tag:example_tag_rule",
      "tag: example_tag_rule2"
    ]
  }
]
```

I'd like to create a csv file with the value within the Name key and all of the "c7n:MatchedFilters" in the array. I've made a few attempts but still can't get quite the output I expect. There's some example code and the output below:

```
#Prints the key that I'm after.
cat new.jq | jq '.[] | [.Tags[], {"c7n:MatchedFilters"}] | .[] | select(.Key=="Name")|.Value'
"example1"
"example2"

#Prints all the filters in an array I'm after.
cat new.jq | jq -r '.[] | [.Tags[], {"c7n:MatchedFilters"}] | .[] | select(."c7n:MatchedFilters") | .[]'
[
  "tag: example_tag_rule"
]
[
  "tag:example_tag_rule",
  "tag: example_tag_rule2"
]

#Prints *all* the tags (including ones I don't want) and all the filters in the array I'm after.
cat new.jq | jq '.[] | [.Tags[], {"c7n:MatchedFilters"}] | select((.[].Key=="Name") and (.[]."c7n:MatchedFilters"))'
[
  {
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "example1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "Irrelevant",
    "Value": "irrelevant"
  },
  {
    "c7n:MatchedFilters": [
      "tag: example_tag_rule"
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "example2"
  },
  {
    "c7n:MatchedFilters": [
      "tag:example_tag_rule",
      "tag: example_tag_rule2"
    ]
  }
]
```

I hope this makes sense, let me know if I've missed anything.

Comment: I've edited your sample input to make it valid JSON, can you [check](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67601395/revisions) I didn't mess anything up?

Comment: Please include the expected output for your sample in the question.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks a lot! I've added an additional statement to demonstrate this failing.

Comment: @oguzismail I've added the outputs as per your suggestion.

Comment: It's still not really clear what output you want. How many columns do you expect in the CSV? How many rows? E.g. do you want a column for tag value, a column for matched filters, and a separate row for each pair? (So in this case one row for `example1` and two for `example2`) Or do all the matched filters go in a single entry somehow, so you only expect two rows? If so, how do you want the matched filters combined?

Comment: Hi @Weeble Yeah that sounds about right, matched filters can be separated by a space - or whatever. So two columns and rows dependant on the size of the json. I'm less bothered about the CSV, I can reformat it myself I think :).

Comment: A concrete example of exactly the output you wanted would be helpful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts are not working because you start out with `[.Tags[], {"c7n:MatchedFilters"}]` to construct one array containing all the tags and an object containing the filters. You are then struggling to find a way to process this entire array at once because it jumbles together these unrelated things without any distinction. You will find it much easier if you don't combine them in the first place!

You want to find the single tag with a `Key` of `"Name"`. Here's one way to find that:

```
first(
    .Tags[]|
    select(.Key=="Name")
).Value as $name
```

By using a variable binding we can save it for later and worry about constructing the array separately.

You say (in the comments) that you just want to concatenate the filters with spaces. You can do that easily enough:

```
(
    ."c7n:MatchedFilters"|
    join(" ")
) as $filters
```

You can combine all this together like follows. Note that each variable binding leaves the input stream unchanged, so it's easy to compose everything.

```
jq --raw-output '
    .[]|

    first(
        .Tags[]|
        select(.Key=="Name")
    ).Value as $name|

    (
        ."c7n:MatchedFilters"|
        join(" ")
    ) as $filters|

    [$name, $filters]|

    @csv
```

Hopefully that's easy enough to read and separates out each concept. We break up the array into a stream of objects. For each object, we find the name and bind it to `$name`, we concatenate the filters and bind them to `$filters`, then we construct an array containing both, then we convert the array to a CSV string.

We don't *need* to use variables. We could just have a big array constructor wrapped around the expression to find the name and the expression to find the filters. But I hope you can see the variables make things a bit flatter and easier to understand.

Comment: You've explained this in a very in depth way, I'm extremely thankful. This is useful to pretty much anyone and everyone planning to use jq for this kind of work, it's really good and detailed.

Thanks again.